# encryption-decryption of form data for storing in local files using cordova for windows platform

Tags: encryption, uwp, cryptography, visual-studio-2017, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to find out a way to encrypt, decrypt form data and store it in local files of the device using Cordova for building windows apps. for Android platform, we can easily do it using simple-crypto plugins. Just trying to find an alternative in windows. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to find out a way to encrypt, decrypt form data and store it in local files of the device using Cordova for building windows apps.

You can call WinRT API in Cordova codes directly, or you can wrap the codes into a [custom plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/). Any way you will have to use [Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/data-protection) to do the job.

Sample js codes:

```
if ((cordova.platformId == "windows")) {
    var Cryptography = Windows.Security.Cryptography;
    //Encrypt the msg string
    function protectData(msg) {
        var provider = new Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider("LOCAL=user");
        var encoding = Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.utf8;
        var buffMsg = Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.convertStringToBinary(msg, encoding);
        provider.protectAsync(buffMsg).done(function (buffData) {
            //the encryption has succeeded
            writeToFile(buffData);
        });
    }
    //decrypt the buffProtected buffer
    function unprotectData(buffProtected) {
        var provider = new Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider("LOCAL=user");
        var encoding = Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.utf8;
        // Decrypt the protected message specified on input.
        provider.unprotectAsync(buffProtected).then(function (data) {
            var stringMsg = Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.convertBinaryToString(Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.utf8, data);
            document.getElementById("divResult").innerText = stringMsg;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    function writeToFile(buffProtected) {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.createFileAsync("test.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
        .then(function (storageFile) {
            Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeBufferAsync(storageFile, buffProtected).done(function(){});
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    function readFromFile() {
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.getFileAsync("test.txt").then(function (storageFile) {
        var abc = storageFile;
        Windows.Storage.FileIO.readBufferAsync(storageFile).then(function (buffData) {
            //decrypt the data
            unprotectData(buffData);
        });
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }


    document.getElementById("btnEncrypt").onclick = function () {
        var data = document.getElementById("txtData").value;
        protectData(data);
    }

    document.getElementById("btnDecrypt").onclick = function () {
        readFromFile(unprotectData)
    }
}
```

And Html:

```
<input type="text" id="txtData" placeholder="ToProtected Data" />
<button id="btnEncrypt">Encrypt Data</button>
<button id="btnDecrypt">Decrypt Data</button>
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

Comment: Here, I'm trying the above code to encrypt form data but an error is coming in the function unprotectData(buffProtected) on statement **"provider.unprotectAsync(buffProtected).then(function (data)"**. The error says **"The parameter is incorrect.."** what could be the possible reason for that. Can you help me with that..?

Comment: Please make sure the data that you want to decrypt was encrypted using  `Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider`. Data encrypted by other API or tools could be undecryptable using this method.

Comment: Yes, data was encrypted using Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider, just like you provided in function protectData(msg). but still, it's not working.